# Vaadin change button style after click

Tags: java, css, button, vaadin

EDIT: pardon if it was not clear, I need a "Vaadin" solution

apparently this should be very intuitive but I can't manage to make it work, when a button is clicked I should change its style, if clicked again, return the style back to what it was. My guess would be:

```
@Override
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Button b = event.getButton();

    if (b == my_special_button){            
        if(!b.getStyleName().contains("x")){
            b.addStyleName("x");                
        } else {
            b.removeStyleName("x");
        }       
    }
}
```

when using chrome inspector I see the active class added, but the button disappears. If I click on the position where the button was, I see the "active" class removed (and added if clicking again..). The button re-appears only when I click outside the area were the button was.

Could you provide some insight?

EDIT: I correct the example code here as suggested (in my class it was already as suggested, I didn't knew it made a difference though, so thanks!)

As the page loads the button has this class:

```
v-button v-button-thumbs-up-button thumbs-up-button
```

when I click, with chrome inspector I can see that the class active is added:

```
v-button v-button-thumbs-up-button thumbs-up-button v-button-active active
```

if I click again, it's removed. So apparently the onclick code is executed correctly.

There are two problems:

1. the "active" style is not applied to the button, the button disappears!
2. if I click outside the button, the button re-appears but style goes back to the non-active one. The non active style works fine, so the css is loaded by the page.

For further reference this is the css I'm using:

```
.thumbs-up-button{
background-image: url("../covercliptheme/img/thumbs_up_1x.png");
background-position: left top;  
}

.thumbs-up-button .v-button-active .active{ 
background-image: url("../covercliptheme/img/thumbs_up_1x_green.png");
background-position: left top;
}
```

I've found workaround with styling :active and :focus too. It is working, but there is no real reason why it should. It should work as I intended originally I think, by adding a class, the button is rendered with that style, removing the class, style goes back to original style.

I think the problem is in the way I've build the page with the components rather than in the onClick action itself.. I'm super curious to find out what is going wrong:) The button is part of a component, which is part of other components, in particular the component with the button is represented by the following class:

```
public class CVRow extends CustomComponent implements Button.ClickListener{

@AutoGenerated
private AbsoluteLayout mainLayout;
@AutoGenerated
private HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout_1;
@AutoGenerated
private AbsoluteLayout absoluteLayout_2;
@AutoGenerated
private Button nativeButton_2;
@AutoGenerated
private Button nativeButton_1;

/**
 * The constructor 
 */
public CVRow() {
    buildMainLayout();
    setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);


    nativeButton_1.addListener(this);
    // TODO add user code here
}

@AutoGenerated
private AbsoluteLayout buildMainLayout() {
    /* some layout code.. */

    // add horizontalLayout_1
    horizontalLayout_1 = buildHorizontalLayout_1();
    mainLayout.addComponent(horizontalLayout_1, "top:0.0px;left:0.0px;");

    return mainLayout;
}

@AutoGenerated
private HorizontalLayout buildHorizontalLayout_1() {
    // some layout code... //


    // add absoluteLayout_2 <-- buttons will be here
    absoluteLayout_2 = buildAbsoluteLayout_2();
    horizontalLayout_1.addComponent(absoluteLayout_2);

    return horizontalLayout_1;
}

@AutoGenerated
private AbsoluteLayout buildAbsoluteLayout_2() {
    // common part: create layout
    absoluteLayout_2 = new AbsoluteLayout();
    absoluteLayout_2.setImmediate(false);
    absoluteLayout_2.setWidth("60px");
    absoluteLayout_2.setHeight("60px");
    absoluteLayout_2.setMargin(false);

            //BUTTONS are here:
    // nativeButton_1
    nativeButton_1 = new Button();
    nativeButton_1.setImmediate(true);
    nativeButton_1.setWidth("20px");
    nativeButton_1.setHeight("20px");
    nativeButton_1.setStyleName("thumbs-up-button");
    absoluteLayout_2.addComponent(nativeButton_1, "top:41.0px;left:0.0px;");

    // nativeButton_2
    nativeButton_2 = new Button();
    nativeButton_2.setStyleName("thumbs-down-button");
    nativeButton_2.setImmediate(true);
    nativeButton_2.setWidth("20px");
    nativeButton_2.setHeight("20px");
    absoluteLayout_2.addComponent(nativeButton_2, "top:41.0px;left:40.0px;");

    return absoluteLayout_2;
}

@Override
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Button b = event.getButton();

    if (b == nativeButton_1){

        if(nativeButton_1.getStyleName().contains("active"))
            nativeButton_1.removeStyleName("active");
        else
            nativeButton_1.addStyleName("active");
    }

            //etc...

}

}
```

Comment: What vaadin version you are useing? Your code is working perfect in my  Vaadin application with the version 7.1.1. Can it be that you are useing the old 6.x version of vaadin?

Comment: Yes, I am using 6.8.12 ..arrr, don't tell me the only way is to migrate

Comment: Ah no, it works also with Vaadin 6.x. I tested it. See my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on your code is, that you check and change the stylename from your Button "b" and not from Button "my_special_button". It have to look like this:

```
@Override
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Button b = event.getButton();

    if (b == my_special_button){            
        if(!my_special_button.getStyleName().contains("x")){
            my_special_button.addStyleName("x");                
        } else {
            my_special_button.removeStyleName("x");
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, I tried but the behavior I see doesn't change, the class name is added and removed but it's like the browser doesn't load the new style. I'll edit the question and specify better what's happening, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Simple example doing it with pure javascript: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KxeUQ/)

HTML:

```
<button id="toggleButton">
    Toggle Class
</button>
```

CSS:

```
button{
    font-size:10px;
}

.active{
    font-size:15px;
}
```

JS:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('toggleButton');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if(this.classList.contains('active')){
        this.classList.remove('active');
    }
    else{
        this.classList.add('active');
    }
});
```